# DIV boxes not aligning

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am having issues trying to get col3 and col4 to align.  I am getting the below - I am trying to get the to align underneath each other inside the red box.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listingAttributes">
<div class="col0">
<span class="name">Bedrooms:</span>
<span class="value">2</span>

<span class="name">Bathrooms:</span>
<span class="value">4</span><br/>

<span class="name">Price:</span></br>
<span class="value">Asking price $1,250,000</span></p>                                                          
</div>
<div class="col1">
<span class="name">Floor area:</span>
<span class="value">200m²</span>
<span class="name">Land area:</span>
<span class="value">1452m²</span>
<span class="name">Rateable value</span>
<span class="value">$980,000</span>                                                                     
</div>
<div class="col2">
<span class="name">Open home times:</span>
<span class="value">
<p>Sat 1 Dec 2 pm - 2:45pm</p>
<p>Sun 2 Dec 2 pm - 2:45pm</p>

</span>
</div>

<div class="col3">
<span class="name">In the area</span><br/>
<span class="value">Schools, Cafe's, Orewa Beach, Surfclub, Orewa Village, Silverdale Mall Wenderholm Park. Boat Ramp</span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="col4">
<span class="name">In the area</span><br/>
<span class="value">Schools, Cafe's, Orewa Beach, Surfclub, Orewa Village, Silverdale Mall Wenderholm Park. Boat Ramp</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.listingAttributes{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 15px 10px -5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFB400;
    background-color: red;
}
.listingAttributes .col0, .col1{
    width:160px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.listingAttributes .col2{
    width:180px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.listingAttributes .col3{
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.listingAttributes .col4{
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;   
}
.listingAttributes .sectionListingAttributes, .name{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear your parent class** `.listingAttributes`

```
.listingAttributes{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

### --------

I think you should **remove** `display:inline-block` because you are using `floating` and **clear to your parent**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/UEMxg/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

its because the width of content in green div is more than green div

and try

```
<div class="col0">...</div>
<div class="col1">...</div>
<div class="col2">...</div>
<div class="col3">...</div> //    width: 230px; in  style
<div class="col4">...</div>//  width: 230px; in  style
<div style="clear:both"></div> <---clear both here
```